# Any idea unity game 2d coins reset when starting new game

Tags: unity, javascript

I am newbie any help would be really much appreciated thanks in advance :) Example I am game over I earned 30 coins and start new game and coin in the game start with 0 and the coins collected in previous game is gone.

This is my code ....

*coin collected*:

```
     private var score : int=0;
     var saved ;
   public static var coins : float;
   private var coinsBegin : int;

  function Start () {
     saved = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("Coin");

    }


    function OnTriggerEnter2D( other : Collider2D ) {
          if (other.tag == "Coin") {
       coins += 1; 
      PlayerPrefs.SetInt ("Coin", coins);
      coinsBegin++;
     PlayerPrefs.GetInt("Coin");
     DontDestroyOnLoad (other.gameObject);
            PlayerPrefs.Save();
            Destroy(other.gameObject);


          }

         }

        function OnGUI () {
         GUI.Label (Rect (20, 20, 200, 40), "score: "                +PlayerPrefs.GetInt("Coin"));

          }
```

and this is ... *coin display*:

```
     #pragma strict var MyFont : Font;

   function OnGUI(){
      GUI.skin.font = MyFont;
        GUI.Label(Rect(100,100,50,50), "Coins: "+   PlayerPrefs.GetInt("Coin"));
   PlayerPrefs.Save();
        }
```

Comment: There is a lot of code here which doesn't make a lot of sense. Why are you calling `PlayerPrefs.Save();` in various places where you just read from it and didn't write anything? Why do you call `PlayerPrefs.GetInt("Coin");` without assigning the return value to anything? Why do you call `DontDestroyOnLoad` on coins *when they are collected* and then destroy them explicitly just two lines later?

Comment: Please avoid [cross posting from SO](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/40135516/1).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently you are trying to save the number of coins the player earned in the PlayerPref's. Your are even reading them in your Start function with `PlayerPrefs.GetInt("Coin");`. However, you are then storing the result in a variable `saved` which isn't used anywhere. Store the return value in `coins` instead (which I think should be an `int`, not a `float`, by the way).

Answer (score 0):

Replace your Start function with this:

```
function Start () {
     coins = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("Coin");
}
```